# Cannot get swagger.json

Tags: java, json, spring, swagger, swagger-2.0

I have a jax-rs spring rest web app where I want to add swagger doc.

In my web.xml this was already defined for my existing REST API:

```
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>com.bloom.rest.jaxrs.JaxrsApplication</servlet-name>
    <!-- Force immediate loading -->
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>com.bloom.rest.jaxrs.JaxrsApplication</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/v1/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

I added Swagger configuration in my servlet: JaxrsApplication

```
        BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
        beanConfig.setVersion("1.0.2");
        beanConfig.setSchemes(new String[]{"http"});
        beanConfig.setHost("localhost:8080");
        beanConfig.setBasePath("/v1");
        beanConfig.setResourcePackage("com.bloom.rest.endpoints");
        beanConfig.setScan(true);
```

I also added swagger beans in my context xml file:

```
<bean id="apiListingResource" class="io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource" />
    <bean id="swaggerSerializers" class="io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.SwaggerSerializers"
        scope="singleton" />
```

Seems that the scanning of my resources works fine:

```
 INFO  AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
 INFO  JestClientFactory - Node Discovery Disabled...
 INFO  ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 7821 ms
 INFO  Reflections - Reflections took 84 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 66 keys and 276 values
```

but http://localhost:8080/v1/swagger.json is not working (gives 404).

I have tried a lot of cases (with v1 in swagger conf, without, etc) but something is missing. Do you have any ideea?

My existing api like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/v1/users/34
```

works. Just that the newly added swagger not.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an `Application` class and not Spring's scanning, you most likely specify your resources in that class and that's why the bean definitions don't get picked up. Try adding both `io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource` and `io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.SwaggerSerializers` as resources to your `Application` class.